# Why png files doesn't paste correctly in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, png, android-drawable

[image]

Why the file uva_icona isn't recognized as png file when I paste it in the res\drawable folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I found the issue. I must paste png file in drawable directory but when it shows windows with destination folder I must erase .png extension from the file name as shown in the picture. Then files are properly paste and they shows correct image icon

[image]